# Coordinates of Buttons in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uibutton, coordinates

i'm fairly new to swift and programming and have a very simple question.
I have four buttons with custom images in the UI and i'm trying to put a surrounding Graphic behind the pressed Button. Here's the line of code:

```
@IBAction func moodButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    timerSelection.center = CGPointMake(moodButton.center.x, moodButton.center.y)

}
```

`timerSelection` is the `UIImageView` i'm trying to put to the coordinates of the selected button...

Please Help! & Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
@IBAction func moodButton(sender: UIButton) {
    timerSelection.center = sender.center
}
```

You can send this subview to back before:

```
view.sendSubviewToBack(timerSelection)
```